# How to iterate over DataFrame and generate a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame looks like this:

```
P Q L
1 2 3
2 3 
4 5 6,7
```

The objective is to check if there is any value in `L`, if yes, extract the value on `L` and `P` column:

```
P L
1 3
4,6
4,7
```

Note there might more than one values in `L`, in the case of more than 1 value, I would need two rows.

Bellow is my current script, it cannot generate the expected result.

```
df2 = []
ego
other
newrow = []

for item in data_DF.iterrows():
    if item[1]["L"] is not None:
        ego = item[1]['P']
        other = item[1]['L']
        newrow = ego + other + "\n"
        df2.append(newrow)

data_DF2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Comment: Are you values in L lists, a string of numbers, etc.. can you post raw input data and code to reproduce your df

Comment: **You need to post the raw data**, so we can see if the values in L are '' (empty string), NaN, or something else. And did they come in from `pd.read_csv()`, and if so, which dtypes and arguments were specified? You can tell `read_csv` how you want it to handle NaNs, and you can defined '' as a NaN value. So you can prevent this issue ever arising.

Comment: This is avoidable, and a possible non-issue. You're probably creating the issue yourself, possibly with `pd.read_csv()`. You haven't given enough detail to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I extract multiple values of column `L` to new dataframe `s` with duplicity index from original index. Remove unnecessary columns `L` and `Q`. Then output join to original `df` and drop rows with `NaN` values.

```
print df
   P  Q    L
0  1  2    3
1  2  3  NaN
2  4  5  6,7

s = df['L'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1) # to line up with df's index
s.name = 'L'
print s
0    3
2    6
2    7
Name: L, dtype: object

df = df.drop( ['L', 'Q'], axis=1)
df = df.join(s)
print df
   P    L
0  1    3
1  2  NaN
2  4    6
2  4    7
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
print df
   P  L
0  1  3
1  4  6
2  4  7
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can extract all rows of the `L` and `P` columns where `L` is not missing like so:

```
df2 = df[~pd.isnull(df.L)].loc[:, ['P', 'L']].set_index('P')
```

Next, you can deal with the multiple values in some of the remaining `L` rows as follows:

```
df2 = df2.L.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
df2 = df2.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'L'}).dropna()
df2.L = df2.L.str.strip()
```

To explain: with `P` as `index`, the code splits the `string` content of the `L` column on `','` and distributes the individual elements across various columns. It then stacks the various new columns into a single new column, and cleans up the result.

Answer (score 0):

I was solving a similar issue when I needed to create a new dataframe as a subset of a larger dataframe. Here's how I went about generating the second dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1','column2'])
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['company_id'] == 12345 or row['company_id'] == 56789:
        df2 = df2.append(row, ignore_index = True)
```